# How to splice array and merge back

Tags: ruby, algorithm, multidimensional-array

Say I have a 2D array like so:

```
[ 3,    4,   8,   12 ]
[ 2,    6,   7,   16 ]
[ 1,   10,  11,   15 ]
[ 5,    9,  13,   14 ]
```

I want to `shift` the `6` at `[1][1]` and `unshift` it into `[2][1]` so that I get the following:

```
[ 3,    4,   8,    12 ]
[ 2,    7,   11,   16 ]
[ 1,    6,   10,   15 ]
[ 5,    9,   13,   14 ]
```

I thought I'd `splice(1,1)` on the second and third arrays to get:

```
a: [6, 7]
b: [10, 11]
```

and then do:

```
b.unshift(a.shift)
a << b.pop
```

Comment: Yup sorry it was an accident. Its related to ruby

Comment: In your example you appear to be “rotating” the elements of the sub-array `[[6,7], [10,11]]`, but have not stated that. Please elaborate with an edit. If you are moving the element at `[i,j]` to `[k,l]` are there any restrictions on `[k,l]`? For example, must `k=i` or `l=j`?

Comment: I’ve downvoted the question. You’ve made it clear in a comment below that you wish to convert the first array above to the second array; not a general solution, but those two specific arrays. You don’t need to manipulate the first array with code to do that—just write the second array as a literal in the same way you’ve written the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this array:

```
ary = [
        [ 3,    4,   8,   12 ],
        [ 2,    6,   7,   16 ],
        [ 1,   10,  11,   15 ],
        [ 5,    9,  13,   14 ]
      ]
```

You can do it by parallel assignment:

```
ary[2][1], ary[1][1], ary[2][2], ary[1][2] = ary[1][1], ary[1][2], ary[2][1], ary[2][2]
```

Maybe you can turn it into a method.

Comment: Multiple assignment is the official name, by the way: https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Multiple+Assignment

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate this concept in Ruby. Its so handy!

Comment: This only works for the specific example. What’s the point of that? You may as well just construct the new array as a literal. The essence of the problem is how to do that for an arbitrary array and an arbitrary pair of locations in the array.

Comment: @CarySwoveland The thing is, I was actually planning to do this arbitrarily. But this is out of the scope of this question. I can create another question that aims for aribitrary size